# Coinbase send_money API always returns "amount is below the current minimum" error

Tags: python, python-requests, bitcoin

I'm trying to send some btc using an authenticated access_token to another coinbase address. Everything seems to be working, except Coinbase always responds with 'amount below minimum.' Can anyone catch what I'm doing wrong here?

```
url = "https://coinbase.com/api/v1/transactions/send_money?access_token=XXX"
params = {
             "transaction": { 
                 "to": "1G8f9pRvgprVMUymuQugZrhYSqBNXuwzNt", 
                 "amount": "0.011", 
                 "notes": "Testing transaction" 
             }
         }

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(params)
```

Coinbase returns:

```
{
   "success":false,
   "errors":["You must enter a positive amount","This transaction amount is below the current minimum amount to be accepted by the bitcoin network. (0.00005430 BTC)"],
   "transaction":{"id":"XXX",
                  "created_at":null,
                  "hsh":null,
                  "notes":null,
                  "amount":{"amount":"0.00000000","currency":"BTC"},
                  "request":false,
                  "status":"pending",
                  "recipient_address":""
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh. Forgot to set the headers :(

This works:

```
url = "https://coinbase.com/api/v1/transactions/send_money?access_token=XXX"
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
params = {
             "transaction": { 
                 "to": "1G8f9pRvgprVMUymuQugZrhYSqBNXuwzNt", 
                 "amount": "0.011", 
                 "notes": "Testing transaction" 
             }
         }

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(postData), headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is getting this error using Coinbase API v2 - you can only send micropayments to a Coinbase email, not any bitcoin wallet.